# Desktop Hyperlink to Specific time in a video

Tags: mac, video, vlc-media-player

Using a Spreadsheet, I pasted this URL in:

```
    file://localhost/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/username/Tutorials/Photoshop/Using Layers.mp4
```

When I click on it, it opens up the video in VLC and it starts to play.  So far, so good.  Now, is it possible to add a time parameter to the URL so that the video will start play at a certain time, instead of at the beginning?

Comment: Via a hyperlink, only if the opening program (VLC in this case) takes additional parameters that specify time; there's no standard way to specify a time with the `file:` URI scheme, because most files don't have a "time" offset. You could also see if your video player supports its own URI scheme - something like `vlc://<path>?time=<target>` or similar - but again, that's something the player itself would need to implement, and to have registered on the PC when installed.

Comment: A *desktop shortcut* could probably do it, if VLC has a command-line parameter to open the media at a specific time point. However, that's different from a URL. You could embed a shortcut file into an Excel spreadsheet, but it might not work on any computer but your own.

Comment: VLC does have command line parameters.  Some claim start-time does not work.  I have seen working (it's claimed) examples that work on a PC, I've yet to hear of a working Mac example.